# Coordination compound nomenclature for [Cu(acac)(bpy)]BPh4

Tags: nomenclature, coordination-compounds

The title says it all really.

I thought it would be acetylacetonatobipyridinecopper(II) tetraphenylborate. Is this correct? I feel as though it looks a bit clumsy and wasn’t sure if I was supposed to include as (2,2-bipyridine)? Is it ok to use brackets like this for naming a coordination compound the IUPAC way or is my first naming correct?